# Dropdown list is not working in the Asp.net Blazor Component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to learn the new feature in ASP.NET Blazor. I am using Visual Studio 2019. I am trying to create an Ideas Registration form. So the code for dropdownlist i had took from Bootstrap 4. It was not working as expected. Can you please tell me where i am working wrong?

Just a little overwhelmed here, any advice would be much appreciated.

Given Code:

```html
<!-- Card Body -->
<div class="card-body">
    <!-- <form   -->
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <!-- Basic dropdown -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle mr-4" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Basic dropdown
        </button>

        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">.Net</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Python</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Data Science</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Basic dropdown -->
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> where i am working wrong

1. According to the official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#data-toggledropdown-still-required):

   > *Regardless of whether you call your dropdown via JavaScript or instead use the data-api, data-toggle="dropdown" is always required to be present on the dropdown’s trigger element.*

   I would suggest you should wrap your Basic dropdown in the following structure

   ```
    <div class="dropdown">  
         <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="..." > ...</button>
         <div class="dropdown-menu ...>
             ...
         </div>
    </div>
   ```
2. You didn't add an event handler for selection. At least you should add a `@onclick` for the toggle button. When clicking this button, show or hide the `dropdown-menu`.
3. Finally, if you want to implement the dropdown component with Blazor(without javascript), you should also replace the text content within the toggle button when someone selects a dropdown list item.

### A Demo : How to Create A General Dropdown Component

Rather than simply fixing the issue, I think it's much better to create a general dropdown Component so that we can always invoke them in following way:

```
@{ var list = new List<string>{ ".NET", "Python","Java" }; }
<Dropdown TItem="string" OnSelected="@OnSelected" >
    <InitialTip>This is a dropdown list</InitialTip>
    <ChildContent>
        <DropdownListItem Item="@list[0]">.NET</DropdownListItem>
        <DropdownListItem Item="@list[1]">Python</DropdownListItem>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <DropdownListItem Item="@list[2]">Java</DropdownListItem>
    </ChildContent>
</Dropdown>

@code {
    private void OnSelected(string selection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(selection);
    }
}
```

Here the `TItem` is a generic type parameter that is the type of each dropdown list item and can be any .NET type.

**Demo**

[image]

**How-To**

1. Add a `Shared/Dropdown.razor` component:

   ```
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
   @typeparam TItem
   <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle mr-4" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" @onclick="e => this.show=!this.show " 
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               @Tip
       </button>
       <CascadingValue name="Dropdown" Value="@this">
       <div class="dropdown-menu @(show? "show":"")" >
           @ChildContent
       </div>
       </CascadingValue>
   </div>

   @code {
       [Parameter]
       public RenderFragment InitialTip{get;set;}
       [Parameter]
       public RenderFragment ChildContent{get;set;}
       [Parameter]
       public EventCallback<TItem> OnSelected {get;set;}

       private bool show = false;
       private RenderFragment Tip ;

       protected override void OnInitialized(){ this.Tip = InitialTip; }
       public async Task HandleSelect(TItem item, RenderFragment<TItem> contentFragment)
       {
           this.Tip= contentFragment.Invoke(item);
           this.show=false;
           StateHasChanged();
           await this.OnSelected.InvokeAsync(item);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add a `Shared/DropdownListItem.razor` component:

   ```
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
   @typeparam TItem
   <a class="dropdown-item" Item="@Item" @onclick="e=> Dropdown.HandleSelect(Item, ChildContent)" >@ChildContent(Item)</a>

   @code {
       [CascadingParameter(Name="Dropdown")]
       public Dropdown<TItem> Dropdown {get;set;}

       [Parameter]
       public TItem Item{get;set;}
       [Parameter]
       public RenderFragment<TItem> ChildContent {get;set;}
   }
   ```

Comment: itminus this is very helpful.  Can you tell how to close the dropdown list  by clicking anywhere outside it?

Comment: Joe - just worked this out myself. To close on an off click, handle the @onblur event on the main div in Dropdown - in this event method set the "show" variable to false and call StateHasChanged()

Comment: Hi Joe & Wanabrutbeer, I have implemented as above and it's working fine, but not able to handle close dropdown while clicking outside. I have tried @onblur event in main div but it could not fire. can you please guide me to achieve this?  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For DropdownListItem.razor, change the "@onclick" to @onmousedown. For Dropdown.razor inside "@onclick", change !this.show to true and add "@onblur" event. Use a method with body so as to set show to false and call StateHasChanged() as well.

Comment: Fine. If anything, you should add an option if the user doesn't want to be selected, e.g. Escape key. As you are selecting an item it is mandatory to close the list.

Answer (score 18):

Keep in mind that bootstrap dropdown requires bootstrap javascript to be referenced. And the Blazor template doesn't reference it by default.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This isnt the case for blazor, unless you create the component and add interaction to the underlying javascript via the interop.

Comment: Yes this works, you should put those line in /Pages/_Host.cshtml under <body> section.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is great. However, as many have pointed out, the dropdown does not close if an option is not selected. The suggestion to create an @unblur event does not solve the case, as @unclick and @unblur do not seem to work together in .NET 5 (I read somewhere that it does works in the new .NET 6) - @unblur prevents @unclick to be triggered.

I found this solution ([@onblur prevents @onclick in blazor server side app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571088/onblur-prevents-onclick-in-blazor-server-side-app)), changing the @onclick to @onmousedown and then creating the @onblur event (as suggested) has fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The data-toggle = "dropdown" is necessary to trigger the dropdown element. You can look at the basic way of creating dropdown menus in **https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#data-toggledropdown-still-required**. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me only nav bar wrapper worked:

```
                                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
                                <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Click
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
                                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" @onclick="() => Do()">Do First</button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" @onclick="() => DoMore()">Do Second</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
```