# @onblur prevents @onclick in blazor server side app

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Consider the following case

```
<div class="dropdown @(ShowDropdown ? " show" : "")">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" @onfocus="(async (e) => { ShowDropdown = true; })" @onblur="(async (e) => { ShowDropdown = false; })" @bind="SelectedWord" />
    @SelectedWord
    <div class="dropdown-menu @(ShowDropdown ? " show" : "")">

        @foreach (var word in words)
        {
            <button class="dropdown-item" @onclick="(async (e) => SelectedWord = word)">@word</button>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
   private bool ShowDropdown = false;
   private string SelectedWord = "";

   private string[] words = { "word 1", "word 2", "word 3", "word 4" };
}
```

the @onclick event doesn't get triggered unless I remove @onblur.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap `onclick` for `onmousedown`. It's an event ordering issue in the browser but this should solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution which suited my scenario better was to just add a small timeout to let the button have a chance to be triggered, something like:

```
@if (Project.ShowCopy)
{
    <td style="width: 10%;">
        <MudFab Class="mt-2 ml-5" Color="Color.Primary" @onclick="() => Copy(Project)" StartIcon="@Icons.Filled.CopyAll" Size="Size.Small" />
    </td>
}

<MudTextField @bind-Value="CurrentWeek.Monday"
              @onfocus="() => OnDayFocus(MondayThisWeek, Project)"
              @onblur="() => OnBlurTime(MondayThisWeek, CurrentWeek.Monday, Project)"
              Label="@(MondayWithMonthStr)"
              For="@(() => CurrentWeek.Monday)"
              Placeholder="8:00"
              HelperText="@(IsLastProject ? "Monday" : "")"
              Variant="Variant.Outlined"
              Adornment="Adornment.Start"
              Style="padding: 0;">
</MudTextField>

private void OnBlurTime(DateTime date, string text, ProjectModel project)
{
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    project.ShowCopy = false;
    //state changes below
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, in my case i had an expandable menu that was closing onblur instead of NavLink.